# Linq First or Single have drastic effect on performance

Tags: performance, linq

I found that adding `.First()` after `Take(1)` in the following LINQ query

```
{
    var qty= (from ii in Inventory
               where ii.Part == "abc" & ii.Zone == "xyz"
               select ii.Qty).Take(1);
}
```

increases execution time several thousand times. Same with `.Single()`. Wondering why. Note that even without `First` the result already has only one record.

**Full code:**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class SurroundingClass
    {
        class part
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string zone { get; set; }
            public int qty { get; set; }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<part> inventory = new List<part>();
            for (var i = 1; i <= 50000; i++)
                inventory.Add(new part() { id = System.Convert.ToString(i), zone = System.Convert.ToString(i), qty = 3 });
            object qty1;
            DateTime d0 = DateTime.Now;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 20000; i++)
                qty1 = (from x in inventory
                        where x.id == "40000" & x.zone == "40000"
                        select x.qty).Take(1).First();
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(((TimeSpan)(d1 - d0)).Seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I found that adding ".First()" after "Take(1)"* Why would you need it?

Comment: `First` and `Single` actually materialize the result. So it runs a query in the background. `Take(1)` still returns `IQueryable`/`IEnumerable` and doesn't actually do anything, it just prepares the query and delays the outcome until you actually do anything with it.And in this sample, you don't.

Comment: Side note: use `StopWatch` for time measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code example you are not executing query, only creating it.

`First()`, `Single()`, `ToArray()` and some other methods triggering [query execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) / enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Vladimir 's answer, you need to be aware of between `Deferred` and `Immediate Query` Execution in LINQ.

From that point: `.First()` and `Single` or even you `foreach`, `For Each` loop, it called [`Immediate Query Execution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#immediate-query-execution).
So that's the reason why your query `increases execution time several thousand times.`

Some tips **which one should you use?**:

**Immediate Query Execution**

1. If you want to cache the results of a query.
2. If you want to get the final result without re-executing query.

**Deferred Query Execution**

1. If you want to build the complexity of a query in several steps by separating query construction from query execution.
2. If you want to fetch the latest information.

Comment: Do you guys have any recommendations on how to improve the performance of this query?